# What's the difference between Broken Pipe and Connection reset by peer?

Tags: networking, broken-pipe, connection-reset

During my daily job, I need to keep connecting to sever through SSH, and I usually got two different kinds of errors, the first one is "Broken Pipe" while the second one is "Connection reset by peer".

I'm wondering what's the difference between these two set of errors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't one really. Both indicate that the connection is broken. 'Broken pipe' is a Unix thing, doesn't happen on Windows as far as I know, and possibly it only occurs on write, where 'connection reset' can occur on both read and write.